# Recursive SQL query to get all components of a part

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion

Given the two tables `Part` and `Structure` as shown below, I would like to write a SQL query that returns a list with a description of all the parts that make up the engine and the quantity of each.

This needs to be a recursive statement, doesn't it? I guess, it also needs `SUM`. The engine consists of a casing and screws but the casing itself consists of screws, too. Thus, the result of the query should be:

| description | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| casing | 1 |
| screw | 10 (= 2 + 8) |
| bearing | 1 |

The two tables are:

**Part:**

| part_no | description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | engine |
| 2 | casing |
| 3 | bearing |
| 4 | screw |

**Structure:**

| part_no | component_no | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 |

Your help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Available solutions will vary according to what DBMS is being used. Please tag the one you are using (e.g. MySQL, SQL-Server).

Comment: Can I ask why `bearing` doesn't appear in your expected results?

Comment: You are right, I added `bearing`to the expected results. Thank you very much!

Comment: @lemur.01 . . . Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need this to be recursive if some of the components themselves have further structure. Your data nests only one extra level, which you could handle by a self-join and/or a union. If you have any further nesting of components, such an approach starts to get very complicated. My code below handles this with a recursive CTE.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS
(
SELECT
    s.component_no,
    p.description,
    s.quantity
FROM
    part p
    JOIN structure s ON 
        p.part_no = s.component_no
WHERE 
    s.part_no = 1 --the part number of what you are making goes here.

UNION ALL

SELECT
    s.component_no,
    p.description,
    s.quantity
FROM
    part p
    JOIN structure s ON 
       p.part_no = s.component_no
    JOIN cte ON 
       cte.component_no = s.part_no
)

SELECT 
   cte.description,
   SUM(cte.quantity) as quantity
FROM
   cte
GROUP BY
   cte.description
```

You can run this code over at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0d7e4d98d21e0a363413b63d6b051b28)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer!
"You only need this to be recursive if some of the components themselves have further structure. That doesn't seem to be the case in your sample data". 
As the engine consists of a casing and the casing itself consists of screws, this is the case even in this small example, isn't it? Or do I get something wrong here?

Comment: Could it be done without recursion (with the given data)?

Comment: I could have expressed that better. Yes, the recursion does do something here, but it could also be handled by a single self-join in this case, i.e. bringing in the structure table twice within the same query. I generally draw the line at brining in a table for a third time and have it handled by recursion. But the more I think about it, perhaps it's better this way even in the simple case. I'll tweak my wording.

Comment: Okay, that clarifies things!